# Oracle : How do i check if user already granted for connect,resource,a particular role or a security package?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I just want to know if a user has already granted access with the below items

1. Connect
2. Resource
3. a particular role
4. a particular package

Thanks a lot in advance for your help and time.

Answer (score 1):

CONNECT and RESOURCE are both roles. So to check what roles a particular user has, use the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM dba_role_privs WHERE grantee='SCOTT';
```

If you want to know if a particular user has EXECUTE permissions on a particular package, use the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM dba_tab_privs WHERE owner='SCOTT' AND table_name='MY_PACK';
```

Note that privileges, that were granted through a role are not listed here.